# How to accept an int in a another activity & use if statement

Tags: android

This is basically the situation im in
(view link)
[Getting RadioButton cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365077/getting-radiobutton-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type/26087814#26087814)

i have an integer storing values for the radio buttons - however, i dont know how to accept it in the other activity.
This is what i have so far (but i get an error)

```
Intent i = getIntent();
int value = intent.getIntExtra("inputValue", a);
    if(a = 1)
    {
        //Enter action
    }
```

Comment: My error is that "a cannot be resolved as a variable"

Comment: The parameter where a is is supposed to be the default value. Just put the number there that you want to get when the intent does not contain any extra with that key. And if you want to compare the retrieved value to 1 then you have to do it like this: `if(value == 1) { ... `

Answer (score 2):

Use `value` in if condition to check `inputValue` from previous Activity :

```
int value = intent.getIntExtra("inputValue", 0);
if(value == 1) {
    //Enter action
}
```

Also `Intent.getIntExtra` take first argument as `key` and second as `default value an int` if key not found in intent.